# MS SQL SERVER - Looping header and detail

Tags: sql-server, database

I am new with MSSQL SERVER. I am having a challenge with looping.

Here's my scenario:

I have a transaction table that is filled with data from SMS messaging.
(tbl_sentTransaction)

Here is how it looks like:

```
TransCtr|TransNum|TransInfo
---------------------------
      1 |11111111|some info 1
---------------------------
      2 |11111111|some info 2
---------------------------
      3 |11111111|some info 3
---------------------------
      4 |11111111|some info 4
---------------------------
```

Now, from tbl_sentTransaction, I have to insert it to its own table.

So I have a header table and detail table.

Here's what I want to do.

If the record from the tbl_sentTransaction has the same TransNum, I will treat it as one record.  So I will insert the TransNum to the header table once.

Then I will insert the TransInfo to the detail table multiple times. So based on the given example:

```
tbl_trans_header

------------------
TransCtr|TransNum
------------------
      1 |11111111
------------------



tbl_trans_detail

------------------------------
TransCtr|TransNum|TransInfo
-------------------------------
      1 |11111111| some info 1
-------------------------------
      1 |11111111| some info 2
-------------------------------
      1 |11111111| some info 3
-------------------------------
```

Would you help me achieve this? I can't make it work. Hope I explained myself well. Thankyou so much. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: which is unique for each transaction? TransNum? What is TransCtr?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`/`ON`.

Comment: Your 'new' table `tbl_trans_detail` is an **exact copy** of your old table `tbl_sentTransaction`. How is this going to help you at all? I'd say to get any benefit whatsoever, you would need to add an ID column to `tbl_trans_header` and then reference that ID from table `tbl_trans_detail`, and also remove `TransCtr` and `TransNum` from `tbl_trans_detail`.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for the idea of the unique column. I finally got it. That is why it is failing because I have no unique column to reference. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete transaction table after you process it, you can use following code

```
insert into tbl_trans_detail (
    TransCtr, TransNum, TransInfo
)
select
    TransCtr, TransNum, TransInfo
from tbl_sentTransaction

insert into tbl_trans_header (
    TransCtr, TransNum
)
select distinct
    1, TransNum
from tbl_sentTransaction
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_trans_header (TransCtr, TransNum)
SELECT MIN(TransCtr), TransNum
FROM tbl_sentTransaction
GROUP BY TransNum


INSERT tbl_trans_detail (TransCtr, TransNum, TransInfo)
SELECT MIN(TransCtr) OVER(PARTITION BY TransNum), TransNum, TransInfo
FROM tbl_sentTransaction
```